# How to change a field in every row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table set up like:

```
id         :int
title      :varchar
info       :text
container  :int
status     :int
```

I have some code to change the value of the field 'status' from 1 to 2 and vice  (1 being shown on site and 2 being hidden)

What i need to do now is this:
When i change status to 1, every row that has the same value in the 'container' field gets its 'status' field changed to 2. The website should only display one record for each container

here is my code to change 'status' to 1.

```
(isset($_POST['show'])){
$chk = (array) $_POST['show'];
$p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
$t = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id IN ($p)";
$shown = $link->query($t);
if ($shown){
   $q = "UPDATE example SET status = 1 WHERE id IN ($p)";
   $show = $link->query($q);
}
```

Can anyone help me modify this code to do what i need?

Cheers

Comment: Your data structure is wrong.  You seem to have attributes of `container` in your `example` table.  You should have a separate table for `container` and join in information, such as `status`.

Comment: Could you clarify this to me? 'container' is just a field that holds an int(1, 2 or 3). I have 3 containers on my site you see, you gussed it they are also 1, 2 and 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a particular entry identified by an 'id', that holds a 'container' reference. 
When the status of this entry is set to 1. Any other entries that have the same 'container' reference get their status set to 2.

This is very untested... guess at the column names...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['show'])){
    $chk = (array) $_POST['show'];
    $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk));
    $t = "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id IN ($p)";
    $shown = $link->query($t);
    if ($shown){
        $currentContainer = $shown['container']; // all the records with this container
        $currentId = $p; // must not change this record later


        $q = "UPDATE example SET status = 1 WHERE id IN ($p)";
        $show = $link->query($q);

        $sql = "UPDATE example SET status = 2 WHERE container = '$currentContainer' AND id != $currentId";
        $others = $link->query($sql);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is not very clear to me, I made a few assumptions:

1. `$p` is an array with id's, which the status has to be changed to 1
2. The status of all other rows in the database with the same container must change to 2
3. `$shown` is an associative array with row data
4. You don't know the container value and it has to be retrieved from the database

What the code below does:
The SELECT query gets the container for each id.
Then, for each id, the container is used to update all associated rows to status=2
Then a second UPDATE query sets status=1 for the specified id;
I also added some escaping to prevent sql-injection.

```
(isset($_POST['show'])){
    $chk = (array) $_POST['show'];
    $p = array_keys($chk); 
    $t = sprintf("SELECT id, container FROM example WHERE id IN ('%s')", implode("','", mysql_real_escape_string($p)));
    $shown = $link->query($t);

   foreach($shown as $row) {
       $q = sprintf("UPDATE example SET status = 2 WHERE container = %s", mysql_real_escape_string($row['container']));
       $link->query($q);
       $q = sprintf("UPDATE example SET status = 1 WHERE id = %s", mysql_real_escape_string($row['id']));
       $link->query($q);    
   }
```